# Bootable USB with Windows Server 2016 not installing, loading after many attempts

Tags: usb, partitioning, debian, mbr, bootable-media

Windows Server(2016) put on bootable USB not loading. Have tried to load from both mbr and gpt partitions. I am trying to load it on my Debian machine to turn it into a Windows Home Server 2016. I created the USB using the following command-lines on my Windows 10 pro 1903 desktop.

```
Step 1. Click “start”, input “cmd” in the search box and hit Enter to open the Command Prompt window tool.

Step 2. Type “diskpart” and press Enter to open the Diskpart tool. Type all the following commands and press Enter to execute them one by one.
1. list disk

2. select disk x (x is the number of your USB flash drive)

3. clean

4. create partition primary

5. select partition 1

6. format fs=ntfs quick (if you want to create UEFI bootable USB, type “format fs=fat32 quick”). I assume fs=ntfs is for a GPT partition and the fs=fat32 is for a MBR partition?

8. active
```

I have tried to load it on my Debian machine in both MBR and GPT form but linux will not let this USB load?

Comment: The already installed OS, no matter which one,  is never related to the boot process of external devices, it happens before the OS.

Comment: Maybe I need to say that my goal is to do a simple install. to use the usb with windows server 2016 loaded on it to reformat the existing debian hard drive cleaning off debian and installing the new windows server.

Comment: During the install of Server you delete all partitions and hit next (this is done in the GUI interface, no need to use diskpart), i will install now.